# A menu that is fixed below the viewport and scrolls once in viewport?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I have no idea how to describe this, so the best thing is to link an example: http://www.pascalvangemert.nl/#/profile

Whatever this guy did with that sidebar menu is great and I would love to replicate it. I have tried inspect, but I cannot pinpoint how it works. It seems to me that the menu behaves as if it was fixed in css, but it only becomes visible once scrolling down the viewport... but there is no fade in or other jQuery tricks that I can see. Does anybody have ideas? Here is what I have so far.
HTML:

```
<ul class="nav">
<li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Experience</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.nav
{
    position: fixed;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: "verdana";
    text-align: left;
    z-index: 3;
    right: 30px;
    top: 200px;
}

.nav a
{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ededed;
}

.nav a:hover
{
    color: #000000;
}
```

Also, I am SO lost as to why the .nav still has dots beside the links, even though I have specified *none* for the text-decoration rule and it worked for the underlining...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could us [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/) Affix for this - pretty simple.

```
<div data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="60" data-offset-bottom="200">
  ...
</div>
```

Edit: I meant Affix the first time - apologies friend. On the bright side , its even easier to use Affix.

Comment: I am afraid that is not what I was trying to do, it just highlights the sections during scrolling.

Comment: @Brian Check my edit. I was mistaken with Scrollspy, you will actually need to use Affix.

Comment: Thanks will let you know!

Comment: works great thanks! Never used Bootsrtap before, I did not know it had such capabilities.

Comment: @Brian Bootstrap is my first stop if I need to draft a prototype - its even pretty invaluable in production - even if you are only using its grid system.

Comment: looks like it, my experience so far is limited to JS, JQ and JQM.